# For which condition, a given function is a solution of the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> The function $$f(x,t)=\begin{cases} 
>       \frac{1}{\sqrt t}e^{-x^2/4t} ~~;& t>0, ~x\in\mathbb R \\
>       ~~~~~~0 ~~~~~~~~;& t\le 0,~ x\in\mathbb R 
>    \end{cases}$$is a solution of the heat equation in
>
> $1.~~~\{(x,t):x\in\mathbb R,~t\in\mathbb R\}$
> $2.~~~\{(x,t):x\in\mathbb R,~t>0\}$ but not in the set $\{(x,t):x\in\mathbb R,~t<0\}$
> $3.~~~\{(x,t):x\in\mathbb R,~t\in\mathbb R\}$ \ $\{(0,0)\}$
> $4.~~~\{(x,t):x\in\mathbb R,~t>-1\}$

Clearly, the two first order partial derivative $~u_x~$ and $~u_t~$ do not exist at $(0,0)$, so I think only **option** $\bf{(3)}$ is correct.
However I think that there is another well-explained answer of this question. If anybody have it, please provide to us.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel of the heat equation i.e. the soution of the PDE
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=c \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2},\quad (x,t)\in \mathbb{R}\times (0,\infty)\\
f(x,0)=\delta(x)
\end{cases}$$
is the function defined on the region $\mathbb{R}\times (0,\infty)$(without the constants).

If we consider the function with domain $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ we can see that the function tell us how a constant function $0$ evolves acording to the Heat equation given that, at some time we apply a "perturbation" (in this case on $t=0$). For example the solution $f=0$ means that no external "perturbation" was made.

Now, in your question, if we want a solution as you impose for $t>0$ the PDE that $f$ must satisfy is
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=c \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2},\quad (x,t)\in \mathbb{R}\times (-n,\infty)\\
f(x,0)=\delta(x)
\end{cases}$$

In particular at $t=0$ f itself it's not a function, it is a distribution. On the other hand you defined $f(x,0)=0$ so both conditions $(f(x,0)=0$ and $f(x,0)=\delta(x))$ are mutually exclusive (for $x=0$) and therefore, the only way to define a function is to remove the point ${(0,0)}$.